# Help debug MobilePush send

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, rest, mobilepush

I am trying to use Triggered API to send a Push notification. Can anyone help me debug what could be wrong with this simple code? I have the right Client Secret and ID as well as mobilepushlistid.

```
%%[ Var @body, @callstatus, @response, @resultOfParsing, @accessToken, @email Set @email = AttributeValue("emailaddr") Set @body = '{"clientId": "CLIENTID****", "clientSecret": "SECRET****"}' /* Get access token */ HTTPPost2("https://mcgww30j0hcc710g0740sk8xjkm8.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v1/requestToken", "application/json", @body, True, @callstatus, @response) /* Construct body */ Set @body = Concat('{ "InclusionListIds": [ "RIGHTLISTID" ], "Override": true, "Badge": "+1", "OpenDirect": "OD01" }') /* Retrieve accessToken from response */ Set @resultOfParsing = Substring(@callstatus,17,24) Set @accessToken = CONCAT('BEARER ', @resultOfParsing) /* Trigger a journey using API event - passing authentication and REST body */ HTTPPost2("https://mcgww30j0hcc710g0740sk8xjkm8.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/push/v1/messageList/NjoxMTQ6MA/send", "application/json", @body, True, @callstatus, @response, 'Authorization', @accessToken)  ]%%
```

The problem seems to be in the last call to send the actual push. Any idea what could be wrong? Is it an issue with the URL? Any other way tha tI can debug.

P.S:. I am not a programmer and have never used REST before.

Comment: Figured it out. Issue was I was using OpenDirect for a cloudpage action. Removed that and got it to work.

Comment: Since you've posted both the question and the answer; would you mind sharing what the actual problem was that you were seeing?

Comment: I was getting errors when I tried to publish the webpage with my code. Not sure what the error message was as CloudPages is not the best way to debug AMPScript code. All I had to do was remove "OpenDirect": "OD01"  . I used PostMan to isolate the problem and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Issue was I was using OpenDirect for a cloudpage action. Removed that and got it to work.